# PCI payment gateway and store

Tags: pci-dss

Consider situation:

I made my own payment gateway and it passes vulnerabity tests.

My store **redirects** to this payment gateway. Card details is collected there. Payment is processed there (not stored) and user is redirected back to our store.

So this works basically same as all payments gateways/processors like Paypal, SagePay, Cardinal etc.

Our online store don't event touch card details.

Is it PCI compilant?

Related question:
[PCI Compilance - Custom payment processor](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32457/pci-compilance-custom-payment-processor)

Comment: Why post the same question again? The last edit in your previous question covers this question. Flagged as duplicate.

Comment: Hi 21886, welcome to [security.se]. There is no need to ask two questions, which are almost perfectly identical, twice. Please modify your other question to include any points you feel are missing.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information here to know if it is PCI compliant.  Any system which HANDLES PCI must be PCI compliant, so your payment gateway has to meet PCI requirements.  As long as the payment gateway only passes a token in place of PCI data, then the PCI requirements should be limited to your payment gateway unless you are doing something odd.

If the question is about the store itself, then as long as it isn't handling PCI and is isolated from any systems handling PCI, then it wouldn't have to deal with PCI-DSS policies.  As far as your payment gateway goes, PCI compliance is a complex topic and a general question about if a system dealing with PCI is compliant is probably out of scope and too localized for the Q/A format.  I would recommend hiring a local PCI expert to take a look at your setup.

Comment: simply store is hosted on shared server, and gateway is going to be small server in our office. we can't affort dedicated server for store.

Comment: @AJ This question was closed as an exact duplicate. It will be deleted soon - I suggest you move this answer over there, perhaps as a 2nd section in your answer.